# High beams always on, except when lights off

Tags: honda, crv

Irrespective of headlight switch on parking lights or on headlights
Car: Honda CR-V 07

What's perplexing is why the high beams are on when the switch is in the parking lights position?

*Update*
New combo switch, same problem... Any ideas. Key symptom is high beams on even when only parking light engaged. Also blue indicator in dash shows high beams active even in switch is in parking position

Comment: Hmm. Did you check the switch?

Comment: Took out and cleaned the contacts. Still switches on the high beams.

Comment: Your situation is similar to the one described in [this question](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/12485/675)

Comment: Burnt out low beams doesn't imply high beams turn on automatically. I'm going to get a new combo switch to rule out switch malfunction

Comment: New combo switch, same problem... Any ideas. Key symptom is high beams on even when only parking light engaged. Also blue indicator in dash shows high beams active

Comment: Stupid question: on many cars the high beams are controlled by a separate switch from the ordinary headlights (often on the turn signal stalk) but only come on when the headlights or parking lights are switched on (with their own switch). You are looking at the switch that actually controls the high beams, right?

Comment: Yup. The switch is not the issue. However high beams don't normally come on when the parking lights are on.

Comment: Do you have a voltmeter on hand? If I were in this situation, I would just start tracing the wires to see where the issue is, like starting from the switch, then to the relays & fuse, and so forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faulty MICU! Grrrr..

The MICU (Multiplex Control Unit)/ fuse box had to be replaced. It controls all aspects of the lights and even stores the code for the immobilizer. The switch was not the reason for the fault..

Once it was replaced all is good...

Comment: Would you care to actually expound on what you're talking about? This really doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 2):

Bad Switch in my opinion. Replace it as you have indicated you are going to do.